# Late Nite Teacher Problems: Linking stylesheet

Tags: html, css

my web page isn't linking the stylesheet. Not sure what's going on this is my first time using style sheets. Need to understand if I'm just missing something. Willing to send the whole document if it would assist in understanding where my error would be coming from. I have. pathways are all in root folder. Not sure what I'm missing. HELPPP!!

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>REID RULES IT</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

</link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body class="body">
....
..
.
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
background-image: url('img/logo.jpg');
color:#000305;
font-size: 87.5% /* base font size is 14px */
font-family: Arial, 'Lucida Sanas Unicode';
line-height: 1.5;
text-align: left;
}

 a {
     text-decoration: none;
 }

 a:link, a:visited {
 }

 a:hover, a:active {
 }

 .body {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 70%;
   clear:both;
 }

 .mainHeader img{
     width: 30%;
     height: auto;
     margin: 2% 0;
 } 

.mainHeader nav {
    background-color: #666;
    height:40px;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;


.mainHeader nav ul { 
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

 .mainHeader nav li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple typo. It should be `<link` and not `</link`

Using a validator such as http://validator.w3.org would find you this issue in a second:

> Error: Stray end tag link.